# Meaning of "break out" in "I break out the little plastic women and everybody has a pretty good time." (from Friends)

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

Below is a line from Friends, the TV show, and Pheobe tells off Chandler that his playing foosball is "violent". (since the game involves some men "joined at the waist by a steel bar". I get the joke here.) Chandler replies to this by saying:

> "After they're done playing, I **break out** the little plastic women and everybody has a pretty good time."

Can "break out" also mean "*bring*"? Does he mean he's going to *get* some female plastic toys to pair with the plastic men of the foosball?

I get what he's trying to say and understand the joke but I'm just not familiar with the usage of the phrasal verb "break out" here.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To break things out is to literally remove them from storage or packaging or figuratively make them available to a group of people, for use or consumption. Mainly American. Hey guys! We've finished the project! Break out the beers!

> Break out
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1a: to make ready for action or use
> *break out the tents and make camp*
>
> 1b: to produce for consumption
> *break out a bottle of champagne*